# How to select data from sqllite and show in TextView ( split text with @)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

I use Android studio and this is my sql statement

```
MYTABLE (id, data) VALUES (1,`ab@cdefg@higklmn@opq`);
```

I want to show data in each TextView value and split data by using "@" no need to show "@" in my TextView

Like this:

```
TextView1 = "ab"
TextView2 = "cdefg"
TextView3 = "higklmn"
TextView4 = "opq"
```

Thank you

Comment: The question is... why don't you use multiple columns, instead of a single one which contains multiple values? What kind of optimization do you think you're doing?

Comment: sorry for my question. i am newbie in programming.

Answer (score 0):

After fetching the data from the database, you will receive a string like

```
String result =  "ab@cdefg@higklmn@opq";
//Split it via @ using split function
String arrayOfResult = result.split("@");
```

That's it.
Now run a loop and assign a value to your TexViews

I Hope it will help you